# Regex for /etc/passwd Content

Tags: linux, bash, regex, passwd

I have a collection files from many systems in my enterprise in a store directory (/store/) and I wanted to find all of the passwd files and cat them out to a single file. Intuitively, the command I came up with and use is:

```
find /store/ -name passwd -type f  -exec cat {} + > all_passwds.txt
```

But this also collects the /etc/passwd file that are binary files (I am assuming that some systems symlink to busybox or something). I really just want text-based passwd files.

My next thought is that maybe I could find all /etc/passwd files and pull regex matches. I have been trying for a couple of hours to create a regex that will match the passwd format.

Any help on either creating a regex that will match /etc/passwd files or how to ensure that the command above only grabs text passwd files would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a regex, then `^([^:]*:){6}[^:]*$` is probably sufficient to match seven fields seperated by `:` on each line, so you could do:

```
find /store -name passwd -type f -exec grep -hIE '^([^:]*:){6}[^:]*$' {} + > all_passwds.txt
```

- `-h` omit the filenames in the output
- `-I` skip binary files
- `-E` enable extended regular expressions (ERE)

Answer (score 2):

First: The binaries are likely `bin/passwd` - i.e. the password change tool...

Simple solution that might work if all your wanted `passwd` files are in subdirectories called `etc`:

```
﻿﻿﻿ find /store/ -wholename '*/etc/passwd'
```

This will only find `etc/passwd` files, which *should* be the correct format.

If that's not working, construct a loop with the `file` utility and concatenate only if it is a text file:

```
file /etc/passwd
   /etc/passwd: ASCII text
```

Lastly, I picked the following regex from an old piece of PHP code. Adapt as needed:

```
\w+:\w+:\d+:\d+:[\w\d\s,@()]*:[\w\d\s\/]*:[\d\s\w\/]*
```